# Deployed Angular Application in Azure but on refresh getting URL Rewrite Module Error

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, url-rewrite-module, azure-deployment

We have the angular application deployed in azure, but on refresh application is breaking and we are getting an error, that is saying *"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."*

[image]

[image]

Here is the web.config file present in my angular application

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Angular Routing" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile"
                     negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory"
                     negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension="json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
  <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" />
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Are you using VS Code or Visual Studio ? How you are deploying your Web App ?

Comment: yes @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT , I'm using visual studio code for frontend development. I'm pushing my code to repo, thereafter using azure pipelines, we are triggering the deployment.

Answer (score 1):

> The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has
> occurred.

- This problem occurs because the server  cannot access the configured root directory of the requested location.

  - Make sure that the server can access the configured root directory of the requested location.
- Looks like there is another `web.config` that conflicts with your parent one in dist and amd.
- The 500 error must locate the problematic `web.config` file if detailed errors is enabled.
  In web.config,

```xml
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

- When the angular app was build using

```
ng build --prod
```

Two web.config files will be deployed. One is in the root folder, the other in the assets folder.

- Check your `angular.json` file
  If you find anything like below

```
 "src/web.config"
```

Remove that line

Please refer [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52227036/angular-application-refresh-doesnt-work-when-hosted-in-azure) ,[Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40275148) and [Ref3](https://www.toptal.com/angular/angular-5-asp-net-core)
for more information

Comment: Thank you @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT for your time, I checked there is only one web.config deployed in the azure, also I tried with few of the web.config files which you sent as references, but nothing works. Please let me know if there is anything I'm missing