# Angular 7 web app page refresh gives "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Tags: angular7, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-8.5, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm working on a angular 7 web application which is hosted in IIS in Windows Server 2012 R2. **This is on ASP.NET CORE 2.2.**

When I navigate the application with the domain name it works fine, but if refresh the page I visited, then it gives me "**The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.**"

If I check the developer tools in chrome, it shows me the following error. Please refer the image below:

[image: Error on Chrome developer tool]

This **user-type-selection:1** is the route path and the param value.

I tried to add the **web.config** in the **src** folder on the **ClientApp** and it as an asset in **angular.json**. It add the web.config in the release folder but it give me **500 internal server error** for that.

Anyone has any thoughts about this?

Comment: I suggest you could firstly check you have add below url rewrite rule in your web application's web.config file. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40275148/7609093)

Comment: Yes. I did and it gives me 500 server error.

Comment: Could you please share the details error message about the 500 error?

Comment: In my case, the problems comes when I updated the Angular CLI 7 to 8. According to the documentation, it is possible to compile with both clients projects in version 7, but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue fixed with the following in the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <!--<action type=”Rewrite” url=”/my-app/” /> -->
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Please make user [URL Rewrite extension](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) is installed in IIS.

I tried the above web.config before but without the above extension and it gave me the 500 error because of that.

Happy coding.